# integrate express-ab module for ab testing in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ab-testing

I am developing an application in sailsjs . It is working fine.
I have created 2 view for a controller. Now  want to do a ab test for those 2 views. based ab test result i will decide which view to used and which one 2 delete.

I have checked some node modules for ab testing and found "[express-ab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ab)" is perfect for my requirement .

But I am unable to implement it .

My routing rules are written in routes.js and sample routeing rule is :
    '/notifyme': {
        controller : 'Notifyme',
        action : 'submit'
    }

Thanks